# Data table not showing all data from query

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a query that produces the correct results, after that I can display the records but not in the format I would like. The working format was Student Name,Grade. I would like to only show the student name once in a row and then show each grade. I have code that loses data when displaying the table.

The 1st row loses 0 entries.
The 2nd row loses 1 entry.
The 3rd row loses 2 entries.
This pattern continues until the query has no more data to fetch. I have the following code.

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(s.last_name, ', ',s.first_name) AS 'Student Name',g.grade 
        FROM `grades` g 
            JOIN assignments a ON a.assignment_id=g.assignment_id 
            JOIN teacher t ON t.teacher_id=a.teacher_id 
            JOIN students s ON s.student_id=g.student_id 
        WHERE a.teacher_id='" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "' 
        AND a.subject_id='2' 
        ORDER BY s.last_name ASC";

$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(assignment_name) 
             FROM `assignments` 
             WHERE subject_id = '2' 
             AND teacher_id= '" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "';";

//gets the number of assignments so it can display the table
$resultCount = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlCount);
$countNum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCount);
$counter = $countNum['COUNT(assignment_name)'];
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($counter == 0){
        echo"<tr><td>{$row2['Student Name']}</td>";
        echo"<td>{$row2['grade']}</td>";
        $counter++;
    } else if($counter < $countNum['COUNT(assignment_name)']){
        echo"<td>{$row2['grade']}</td>";
        $counter++;
    } else{ 
        $counter = 0;
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}
```

[Here is my desired final output format. I had to make it a link due to my account being new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDiNf.png)

[image]

Comment: `AS 'Student Name'` Surely that should be wrapped in backticks and not single quotes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The query works, and displays the information when I echo     "<tr><td>{$row2['Student Name']}</td>";
        echo"<td>{$row2['grade']}</td>"; It just doesn't show all the data when I put it in the loops

Comment: If you dont put spaces in variable names you wont need either

Comment: Show u    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: You said data isnt on the format you want, but you dont show us what is the format you want or what result you are getting. So we cant help you to travel from A to B

Comment: Don't see why you need a counter there, just loop the data and change the table row when `'Student Name` changes

Comment: I am using the counter to go to the next row in the table to it displays horizontally, rather than in a vertical list.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I will post a picture of the desired format

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would seem a lot simpler.

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(s.last_name, ', ',s.first_name) AS StudentName,g.grade 
        FROM `grades` g 
            JOIN assignments a ON a.assignment_id=g.assignment_id 
            JOIN teacher t ON t.teacher_id=a.teacher_id 
            JOIN students s ON s.student_id=g.student_id 
        WHERE a.teacher_id='" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "' 
        AND a.subject_id='2' 
        ORDER BY s.last_name,s.first_name ASC";


$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 

$last_stud = null;

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($last_stud != $row2['StudentName']){

        // close previous <tr>
        if ( $last_stud !== null ) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        $last_stud = $row2['StudentName'];
        echo"<tr><td>{$row2['StudentName']}</td>";
        echo"<td>{$row2['grade']}</td>";
    } else {
        echo"<td>{$row2['grade']}</td>";
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: I like this solution. I am still getting a display error with the Bri and Bethany Cochran rows. I'll make an attempt to adjust them and update the results.